# Animated objects as hair particles

Tags: animation, particles

I rigged an object and animated it, and have set it as a hair particle (dupli object). It displays correctly, but animation is not being passed on... How do I make hair particle objects perform animation?

Note: I am aware that animation will be synchronized across all particles and am okay with that.

Comment: Hi there! I just checked it out and it works for me. I made a simple model, added a rig and animated it. Then I made a hair system an setted the hair particles as object: the model. And it works fine. What was your workflow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have your animated model and hair object on the same layer, or it won't update in the viewport (it will work only in render).

[image]

Comment: I could watch this all day long!

Comment: @Jerryno is there a way to randomise this animation

Comment: @ashwin use the group option under particle render and put multiple object copies with different animations inside that group;) Enable *Pick Random* to pick randomly from the group.

Comment: @ashwin also rotating the hair particles randomly will help (*Advanced* > *Rotation*).

Comment: Does is work for a Emitter particle sistem as well?