# Hair particles trouble when animating

Tags: armature, particles

Do you know why hair particles get strange when animating?

Here is the thing: I have a character with a hair particles system for hair.
My character is animated through an armature.
So I move my character, make him following a path, through his armature: and as soon as I move this way, my hair get crazy.

I precise that armature modifier is just above my particle system.

Comment: Try to ckeck the 'Use Modifier Stack' box of Emission tab in Particles header.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already checked this box

Comment: Are the [animated model and hair object on the same layer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23850/animated-objects-as-hair-particles?rq=1) ?

Comment: I built my particles system directly through my character object. I defined my particles thanks to a vertex group on the head to fill the density field.

Comment: I need to precise something that may be important : only the children particles get crazy. Not the parents.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your subsurface modifier is on. Also, you will have different results if the view-port and render subsurf levels are not the same.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with the same problem. One warning though, checking it removed my hair and all hair edits disappeared! Had to regenerate it.