# Grass wind flow in waves

Tags: particles, force-fields

You know how when you look out into a field of grass you see waves of the gusts blowing along? How do you create that in Blender?

Comment: Your question isn't well worded. It sounds like you're asking for a tutorial, which is outside the intended scope for BSE. If you've tried something and are having a hard time understanding how to make it work, or why it doesn't, that'd be a much better question to ask than something as open-ended as what you have here. Try to be specific.

Comment: To make the grass create a **particle sysem** with hair as the emitter type http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/how-do-you-create-grass. To make the wind use a **force field** to generate the wind. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/how-to-make-hair-particles-grass-bend-on-z-axis

Comment: I wanted it to look like this :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qtIvxTeL1c See how it's in waves? What I found out yesterday is to use cylinders to create the "waves" of wind, and just have them graze the top of the grass field.

Comment: Here is waving grass: 
 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5577/how-do-you-create-grass?noredirect=1&lq=1